# How To Use IntelliCode In Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, intellicode

I create the simple `Windows Forms Application` project in `vs 2019 version 16.3.1` with target `.NetCore 3.0`.

when I'm trying to use the `SqlClient` in `System.Data.SqlClient` and use the `open` Method, Appears two `open()` Methods.
one of this method has `*` chars, that is `IntelliCode` Suggestion.

this image:

[image]

how to use `IntelliCode` Suggestion?

Comment: I also found it a bit confusing as to why they added a secondary option, but at the end of the day it’s just assisting you in writing code - there can’t be two methods with the same signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliCode appends suggestions based on context on top of the suggestion list (with a star). In your case it means that based on the context you are the most common used property/method is Open(). Both Open methods in the list are the same.